# Dynamically update Eureka instance metadata

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

When Spring Cloud Eureka instance starts I can define some instance metadata statically (in `eureka.instance.metadataMap.*` in my `application.yml`) or dynamically (using `EurekaInstanceConfigBean` for example). But once instance is registered, this metadata no longer updates in Eureka after I update the config bean.
Is there a way to define some metadata that will dynamically update in Eureka? So Eureka will work kind of like a key-value storage for each instance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to update any metadata from eureka client for itself, just use `com.netflix.appinfo.ApplicationInfoManager`object and call `registerAppMetadata(Map<String, String>)`.
If so, this info will be updated in Eureka Server usually soon or at least in 30sec.You can use DI to get the instance of ApplicationInfoManger.

If you want to update metadata for other service instance, just invoke REST API like below to eureka server.

```
PUT /eureka/apps/appID/instanceID/metadata?key=value
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Exactly what I was looking for. Do you know if this 30sec interval can be adjusted to a smaller one?

Comment: First, you can adjust interval for instance info replication, and it will affect the duration for reporting any changes from your eureka client itself to eureka server. `eureka.client.initialInstanceInfoReplicationIntervalSecond`, `eureka.client.instanceInfoReplicationIntervalSeconds`. But as I wrote above, usually any changes from eureka client will be reported to server on demand. So adjusting these values are not much effective.

Comment: If you want to receive any data changes(including metadata) from another eureka client, there are MANY caches between them - eureka server reponse cache, eureka client cache. So if you want to receive these changes from another eureka client quickly, you also need to adjust other options.

Comment: I can set my meta data, but I can't see it at the /eureka/apps/appID url.  question here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64025298/app-instance-metadata-not-displayed-at-eureka-apps-appid